# How do I delete the same button in another JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, button

For my program, whenever a user adds a button, the button is added to "panel1" and "panel2". So far I can get it to delete whichever button the user desires in the first JPanel, panel1. But how do I delete the same button in my second JPanel according to my code I provided below? Should I check to see if the second panel contains the button with the same name? How should I do this?

```
public class deleteButton
{
   public boolean deleteNow = false;

   class ClickListener implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
            deleteNow = true;
       }
   }
   ActionListener deleteButtonClicked = new ClickListener();
   deleteButton.addActionListener(deleteButtonClicked);

   class ClickListenerTwo implements ActionListener
   {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f)
       {
           JButton buttonThatWasClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
           if (deleteNow == true)
           {

               panel1.remove(buttonThatWasClicked);
               panel1.revalidate();
               panel1.repaint();
               //This is where I want it to delete from panel2.

               deleteNow = false;  
           }
           else
           { 
               System.out.println("The button wasn't deleted");
           }
       } 
   }
```

}

Comment: Maybe you should use a `Map` of some kind or other lookup table

Comment: @MadProgrammer So I can't use "panel2.remove(buttonThatWasClicked)" ? I have to use a "Map" ?

Comment: A component can't reside on two containers at the same time, so you must have two instances of `JButton`, so you need someway to "pair" them together so you find them

Comment: @MadProgrammer It's not exactly the same component, it's whenever the user clicks the "Add" button, a button is made in JPanel panel1 and panel2 with the same name but different functions.

Comment: Okay, same idea, generate some kind of mapping between the two (maybe through the name) so you can ask panel2 for the button that was clicked in panel1 more easily

Comment: How would I do the mapping part? I've never "mapped" anything in Java.

Comment: Maybe start with [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse the component tree to find your button. Something like this

```
/**
 * Searches for all children of the given component which are instances of the given class.
 *
 * @param aRoot start object for search.
 * @param aClass class to search.
 * @param <E> class of component.
 * @return list of all children of the given component which are instances of the given class. Never null.
 */
public static <E> List<E> getAllChildrenOfClass(Container aRoot, Class<E> aClass) {
    final List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    final Component[] children = aRoot.getComponents();
    for (final Component c : children) {
        if (aClass.isInstance(c)) {
            result.add(aClass.cast(c));
        }
        if (c instanceof Container) {
            result.addAll(getAllChildrenOfClass((Container) c, aClass));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/** 
 * Finds the button by its text.
 * @param aParent container for button search.
 * @param aText text of button.
 * @return button with the given text or null if no such button found.
 */
public static JButton findButtonByText(Container aParent, String aText) {
    List<JButton> buttons = getAllChildrenOfClass(aParent, JButton.class);
    for (JButton btn : buttons) {
        if (btn.getText().equals(aText)) {
           return btn;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
JButton btn = findButtonByText(panel2, buttonThatWasClicked.getText());
if (btn != null && btn.getParent() != null) {
   btn.getParent().remove(btn);
}
```

Comment: A `Map` would be quicker, simpler, more efficient and robust

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with the code which delete the component from `JPanel`. Maybe there can be some other problem with the other part of code, but the code below is work well as you want, you can check the logic and edit your code as this:

```
public class DeleteButton extends JFrame {
    private boolean flag;

    public DeleteButton() {
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 400));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Set Flag");
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Delete");
        panel.add(button2);

        button1.addActionListener(e -> flag = true);
        button2.addActionListener(e -> {
            JButton buttonThatWasClicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
            if (flag) {
                panel.remove(buttonThatWasClicked);
                panel.revalidate();
                panel.repaint();
                flag = false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("The button wasn't deleted");
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DeleteButton();
    }
}
```