# swing - setTransferHandler for the whole frame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a frame that contains a button and a text field. I wrote a transfer handler so I can drop files into it. However, when I set the transfer handler on the frame, only the button accepts the drop.

The workaround I have is to set the transfer handler for all the components of the panel.

What is the proper way to do it?

```
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    flowPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(4000, 30));

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);


    TransferHandler newHandler = new TransferHandler() {
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport info) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // downs't work - only the button accepts a drop
    panel.setTransferHandler(newHandler);

    // A workaround - does what I want
    textField.setTransferHandler(newHandler);
    button.setTransferHandler(newHandler);

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(textField);
```

Comment: `The workaround I have is to set the transfer handler for all the components of the panel.` - seems reasonable to me. You can't add a KeyListener to a panel and have it work for all the text fields on the panel.

Comment: Well, in my case I have only one text-field, and anyway my handler knows what to do ...  I add the same handler to all the components, and it works fine.
And if it doesn't work on JFrame. why is it possible to add it at all?

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694511/how-do-i-delete-the-same-button-in-another-jpanel) for the method `getAllChildrenOfClass`

In your case you should use this method as following

```
JFrame myFrame = ...; // your jframe

List<JComponent> comps = getAllChildrenOfClass(myFrame.getRootPane(), JComponent.class);
// you can also use myFrame.getContentPane() instead of myFrame.getRootPane()
for (JComponent c : comps) {
    c.setTransferHanler(newHandler);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Looks like it would work (haven't got the time to check now) but still feels like a hack,

Answer (score -1):

> [Default DnD Support (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing > Drag and Drop and Data Transfer)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/defaultsupport.html)
>   The following components support drop out of the box. If you are using one of these components, your work is done.
>
> - `JEditorPane`
> - `JFormattedTextField`
> - `JPasswordField`
> - `JTextArea`
> - `JTextField`
> - `JTextPane`
> - `JColorChooser`

So I guess you would need to use [JComponent#setTransferHandler(null)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setTransferHandler-javax.swing.TransferHandler-) to remove the  built-in `TransferHandler`.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextComponentTransferHandlerTest {
  public JComponent makeUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JTextField textField = new JTextField("BasicTextUI$TextTransferHandler");
    System.out.println(textField.getTransferHandler());

    JTextField textField2 = new JTextField("setTransferHandler(null)");
    textField2.setTransferHandler(null); //reset default

    JButton button = new JButton("Button");
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);

    TransferHandler newHandler = new TransferHandler() {
      @Override public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info) {
        return true;
      }
    };
    panel.setTransferHandler(newHandler);

    // A workaround - does what I want
    // textField.setTransferHandler(newHandler);
    // button.setTransferHandler(newHandler);

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(textField2);

    return panel;
  }
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
      JFrame f = new JFrame();
      f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      f.getContentPane().add(new TextComponentTransferHandlerTest().makeUI());
      f.setSize(320, 240);
      f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      f.setVisible(true);
    });
  }
}
```